# Como remover o botão voltar no android

Tags: android, android-activity

Como faço para remover esse botão de voltar da minha aplicação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver no oncreate o codigo abaixo voce tire.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Também deve tirar no androidmanifest.xml o ParentAcivity.
ex:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.Telefones"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mostrar_telefones"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.ListaTelefones">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.dtec.listatelefonica2.activity.ListaTelefones" />
    </activity>
```

Deixe somente:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MostrarTelefones"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mostrar_telefones"
        >
</activity>
```

Tirando esses codigos o Up Navigation vai sair

Comment: Muito bom, era exatamente isso que eu precisava.